# How to remove dashes from the end of lines in a file

Tags: bash, sed

macOS.
I'm trying to remove all dashes - from the end of lines in a file but I've not been able to do so. I've tried following commands so far and none worked

```
sed -e 's/^-//' -e 's/-$//' output.txt
cat output.txt | tr -d -
tr -d '[0-9-]' < output.txt
sed 's/[0-9-]//g' output.txt > output1.txt
```

Content of my file output.txt just for example

```
asfdsfds-
asdfdf-
sdfdes dsfds dsfds-
```

Comment: The first command works fine in bash..?

Comment: `tr -d -` works for me? What output did you get from that and what did you expect instead?

Comment: the first `sed` seems to indicate you're looking to remove a single dash from the beginning and/or end of a line; the `cat/tr` appears to delete *all* dashes (multilpe at beginning of line, multiple at end of line, anywhere in the line); the last 2 commands appear to remove all dashes, *and* all digits, anywhere in the line; net result is your coding attempts don't match your description

Comment: your sample data only shows a single dash at the end of the line; is this going to be true of all your data? could you have more than a single dash at the end of the line? could you have dashes anywhere in the line? please confirm that either a) you're only concerned with removing a single dash at the end of the line or b) update the question to show a more representative set of your data; and per your last 2 commands ... if you *are* looking to remove digits from the line then also a) update the decription to state this and b) update the sample data to include some digits

Comment: and regardless of what you're trying to do, please also update the question to show the expected output (making sure the output corresponds to the sample input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only requirement is indeed to remove all dashes from such input file, a single `sed` such as below would be enough :

```
➜  ~ cat output.txt
asfdsfds-
asdfdf-
sdfdes dsfds dsfds-

➜  ~ sed -i '' 's/-//g' output.txt

➜  ~ cat output.txt
asfdsfds
asdfdf
sdfdes dsfds dsfds
➜  ~
```